# How to modify excel autofill?

Tags: vba, excel, autofill, formulas

I have got a timetable. I want to transpose data in rows to column (rather using formulas) in the way which is shown on this picture.

[image: timetable]

In first row (AU,KM,GK,MZ) are teachers, in second one are rooms.

In B23 cell is formula: "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(Q2),ROW(Q2)))"

in B24 "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(R2),ROW(R2)))", 

in B25 "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(Q3),ROW(Q3)))", 

in B26"=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(R3),ROW(R3)))"

I want to fill monday column, but excell autofill is not working like i would like - next formulas are for example q5,r5,q7,r7,q9,r9 instead of simple increasing this way -> q1,r1,q2,r2,q3,r3,q4,r4,q5,r5 etc.

[image: after autofill - problem]

How to fix it? Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B13:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($7:$7,MATCH(A13,$5:$5,0)),"")
```

In B14:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($8:$8,MATCH(A13,$5:$5,0)),"")
```

Then copy and fill both down.

Comment: Ok, i understand what you said about commenting. I'm new here - only that can be my explanation. So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @matoex, the issue is with the differing formats of the time.  In the rows above you are using `:` to denote the difference between hour and minutes, while in the column you are using `.`.  Excel is dumb and cannot intuit that you are meaning the same thing, one is a time the other is a number.

Comment: Ok, I've sent you an email.